# setting up connman to manage a single preferred connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, connection, wifi-configuration

I have a device that has both ethernet and wifi adapters.  I'm trying to use `connman` to manage my connections.  I'd like it to connect to ethernet when it's available and fallback to wifi if there's no ethernet connection.

Here's my /etc/connman/main.conf:

```
[General]
PreferredTechnologies=ethernet,wifi
SingleConnectedTechnology=true
```

What does work:

- if I have the ethernet connected when the device turns on it properly establishes a connection
- if I use `connmanctl` to manually connect to the wifi it will properly switch off the ethernet connection and switch over to the wifi connection

What does **not** work:

- if the device is started up with no ethernet cable then wifi is not established
- if the device was started up and connected to the ethernet then disconnecting the cable does not cause the wifi to connect
- if the device is started up and then the ethernet cable is connected later, it does not connect to the ethernet automatically

I'm using connman 1.15

**EDIT:**

- `/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier` doesn't seem to detect the change in cable connection
- `ip monitor` does seem to be able to detect when the cable is connected or disconnected

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is with the PHY driver. The output of `mii-tool eth0` is `No MII transceiver present!.` indicating it's not working properly.  The strange thing is I **did** have it going at one point and then it stopped again without any changes being made to the driver or kernel.  I suspect there's some sort of bug in the driver.  The PHYceiver in question is the ICplus 101A and I tried the latest linux driver in both the 3.4 and mainline (backported to 3.4) branches.